# How to query a uint256 input contract function via Etherscan's API?

Tags: ethereumjs

I'm trying to query a contract function that takes uint256 as input via Etherscan's API but I keep getting error messages. The format I've realized should be as follows based on [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/76086/what-is-the-abi-code-of-a-maps-getter-function):

[http://etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_call&to=[address]&data=0x[function](http://etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_call&to=%5Baddress%5D&data=0x%5Bfunction) hash]000000000000000000000000[read input]

I got the function hash from remix but I can't find what should be added after it for a uint256 input.

Comment: What's the address of the contract, and the name of the function?

Comment: https://etherscan.io/address/0x60f80121c31a0d46b5279700f9df786054aa5ee5#readContract ownerOf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument must be in hex, padded to 32 bytes.

For example, for `tokenId` 200 (`0xc8` in hex):

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_call&to=0x60F80121C31A0d46B5279700f9DF786054aa5eE5&data=0x6352211e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c8
```

Correctly returns:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x000000000000000000000000b687a0a94d2daeec6814b659c4fb3db3768ff2a1"}
```

Which is the address of the owner of that token, again padded to 32 bytes.