# How to query a contract function via Etherscan's API with uint256 input?

Tags: etherscan, ethereumjs, api

I'm trying to query this contract:
0x992678ad242230Dd795107Fee8B572E27083002A
and to get the "getglobalStakedTokensPerPeriod" (number 11)
with the unit456 of 1 (period 1)

I've tried to use this api:
https://api.etherscan.io/api
?module=proxy
&action=eth_call
&to=0x992678ad242230Dd795107Fee8B572E27083002A
&data=??
&tag=latest
&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

but didn't understand what to put in the "data=" part

I saw this question but still couldn't get it to work using the solution that was provided:
[How to query a uint256 input contract function via Etherscan's API?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98190/how-to-query-a-uint256-input-contract-function-via-etherscans-api)

Answer (score 0):

Etherscan expects encoded calldata as the data argument ([docs](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/geth-parity-proxy#eth_call)).

You can get this multiple ways, including [using ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/utils/abi/interface/-%23-Interface--encoding) (look at the `interface.encodeFunctionData` section), or with `cast calldata` from [foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/cast/cast-calldata).

For your example, using `cast` we can do:

```
$ cast calldata "getglobalStakedTokensPerPeriod(uint256)(uint256)" 11

0x2d9ba1cd000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b
```

We can then pass this to the etherscan API call, and get back something like this:

```
0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080e050bced973
```

Then we need to decode, again according to the function ABI:

```
$ cast --abi-decode "getglobalStakedTokensPerPeriod(uint256)(uint256)" 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080e050bced973

2267214649416051 [2.267e15]
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, I really don't have experience in code, so to make this convert in to encoded data where to I go and use the method you mentioned?

Comment: you can install foundry over and use the commands I mentioned to encode the data. Foundry can be installed here: https://book.getfoundry.sh/getting-started/installation